# ativar onclick no Select de um form

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Preciso fazer que com ao clicar no select ative a `popup` porem não esta funcionando, já o `input` funciona normalmente

```
$("#alert_button").click( function() {
jAlert('Selecione Primeiro o Estado', 'Classificados Publico');
});

<input id="alert_button" type="button" value="Show Alert" />

<select id="alert_button">
<option value="index.php?s=<?php echo "$termo"; ?>" selected> Cidade </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Qual a versão do jquery-ui que você está usando ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arsom, tens dois elementos com a mesma ID.
**IDs têm de ser unicas**. Muda para classes e vai funcionar.

**jQuery**

```
$(".alert_button").click( function() {
    jAlert('Selecione Primeiro o Estado', 'Classificados Publico');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input class="alert_button" type="button" value="Show Alert" />

<select class="alert_button">
    <option value="index.php?s=<?php echo "$termo"; ?>" selected> Cidade </option>
</select>
```

```js
$(".alert_button").click( function() {
    alert('Selecione Primeiro o Estado');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="alert_button" type="button" value="Show Alert" />
<select class="alert_button">
   <option value="index.php?s=termo" selected> Cidade </option>
</select>
```